# Problem with UDF designed to concatenate multiple matches in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this isn't working. It gives me a #VALUE error.

I'm using ActiveSheet because I'll put it on a number of different sheets, and I don't want to have to add a field in the function for that.

LookupRange is designed to find the last row with data in it on ActiveSheet.

My lookup values begin in B5 and extend indefinitely, and the desired matches are in Column O (15th column).

```
Function EmailConcat(LookupValue As String)

Application.Volatile

Dim i As Long
Dim Result As String
Dim LookupSheet As Worksheet
Dim LookupRange As Range

Set LookupSheet = Application.ActiveSheet

LookupRange = LookupSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

For i = 5 To LookupRange.Rows.Count
    If LookupSheet.Cells(i, 2) = LookupValue Then

    Result = Result & LookupSheet.Cells(i, 15) & "; "

    End If
Next i

EmailConcat = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 2)

End Function
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a number to a range. ... .Row is a number and LookupRange is a range.

Comment: Ahhhh. How should I go about fixing that then?

Comment: You should know that by using activeSheet the minute a given sheet is inactive any cells on that sheet using this UDF may start calculating wrong results.  If you want to be safe you should use `Application.ThisCell.Parent` in place of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Tim, that is great advice. I knew of `ThisCell` but didn't know about `Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ThisCell` to ensure results are accurate, and reading the lookup column into an array for better performance:

```
Function EmailConcat(LookupValue As String)

    Application.Volatile

    Dim vals, rv, i As Long, sep As String

    If LookupValue <> "" Then
        With Application.ThisCell.Worksheet
            vals = .Range(.Range("B5"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            For i = 1 To UBound(vals, 1)
                If vals(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
                    rv = rv & sep & .Cells(4 + i, 15).Value
                    sep = "; "
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End If
    EmailConcat = rv

End Function
```

Comment: ThisCell. That's a new one. And even more impressive the sep-trick.

Comment: Thanks so much, Tim. This works perfectly. I don't quite understand why you have to add 4 to i in Cells(4 + i, 15) but not vals(i, 1) in the previous line. Could you please explain the logic there?

Comment: We picked up the range from B5 down, so the first element would be at index (1, 1) - need to adjust that index back to an actual row in Col15 by adding 4.

Comment: Ah, because we're selecting (1, 1) of the `vals` "range" first but then using `.Cells` the second time. Could you accomplish the same thing by replacing `.Cells(4 + i, 15)` with `vals(i, 14)` or would this not work because `vals` is just a column?

Answer (score 0):

## Concatenate Multiple

When using Range or Cells etc. without qualifiers, they refer to the `ActiveSheet` of the `ActiveWorkbook`.

### The Code

```
Function EmailConcat(LookupValue As String)

    Application.Volatile

    Const cFirst As String = "B5"
    Const cCol As Variant = "O"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    For i = Range(cFirst).Row To LastRow
        If Cells(i, Range(cFirst).Column) = LookupValue Then
            Result = Result & Cells(i, cCol) & "; "
        End If
    Next i

    EmailConcat = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 2)

End Function
```

Comment: I got another #VALUE error here unfortunately. The solution from Tim worked, FWIW!